# Strcpy en C con punteros

Tags: c

Estoy creando una funcion en C que copie la cadena `s2` en `s1` pero no funciona y no se dónde esta mi fallo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
char* mi_strcpy(char* s1, char* s2){
    char* puntero = (char*) malloc (mi_strlen(s2)*sizeof(char));
    while(*s2!='\0'){
        *puntero = *s2;
    puntero++;
    s2++;
    }

    *puntero='\0';
    s1 = puntero;
    return s1;
}
void test_mi_strcpy()
{
    char* s1 = "abcdefgh";
    char s2 [9];
    INICIO_TEST("mi_strcpy");
    DebeSerCierto(mi_strcpy(s2, s1) == "abcdefgh");
    FIN_TEST("mi_strcpy");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char* mi_strcpy(char* s1, char* s2){
    char* puntero = (char*) malloc (mi_strlen(s2)*sizeof(char));
    while(*s2!='\0'){
        *puntero = *s2;
    puntero++;
    s2++;
    }

    *puntero='\0';
    s1 = puntero;
    return s1;
}
```

¿Dónde estás usando `s1`? Haces una asignación al final, pero no olvidemos que el puntero `s1`, como tal, es una variable local de tu función. Al principio es un poco complejo de entender, pero fíjate en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
void func(int a)
{ a = 5; }

int main()
{
  int var = 0;
  func(var);
  printf("%d",var);
}
```

Queda claro que el programa va a imprimir `0` porque el cambio que hace `func` es local. Con punteros pasa exactamente lo mismo, el puntero es una variable local y lo único que se comparte con el exterior es lo que se almacene en la dirección de memoria apuntada. Si tu haces que el puntero apunte a otro sitio únicamente estás haciendo un cambio local porque la memoria original **no sufre cambios**.

En tu caso deberías crear un puntero temporal basado en `s1` y trabajar con dicho puntero:

```
char* mi_strcpy(char* s1, char* s2){
    char* puntero = s1;
    while(*s2!='\0'){
        *puntero = *s2;
        puntero++;
        s2++;
    }

    *puntero ='\0';
    return s1;
}
```

Otra alternativa:

```
char* mi_strcpy(char* s1, const char* s2){
  char *puntero = s1;
  do
  {
    *puntero++=*s2;
  } while(*s2++);

  return s1;
}
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices, la verdad con los punteros soy nuevo, porque yo suelo programar en Java. Respecto a tu solucion, me sigue sin dar bien, no me copia bien la cadena.

Comment: @Juanma Nadie nace sabiendo y el tema de los punteros puede llevar un tiempo largo entenderlo del todo

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres copiar una cadena a otra, y estas dando las dos cadenas como parámetros, lo que puedes hacer es modificar la primera cadena pues también es un apuntador. Prueba esto:

```
void mystrcpy(char * s1, char * s2){
    while(*s2!='\0'){
        *s1 = *s2;
    s1++;
    s2++;
    }
}
```

Te deberías encargar de la creación del puntero con su tamaño antes de llamar este método.

**EDITO:**

Cuando se termina de copiar la cadena se agrega el caracter nulo al final, para completarla.
Quedando así:

```
void mystrcpy(char * s1, char * s2){
    while(*s2!='\0'){
        *s1 = *s2;
    s1++;
    s2++;
    }
    *s1='\0';
}
```

Comment: Un detalle: se te ha olvidado finalizar la cadena `s1`

Comment: A qué te refieres con finalizarla?

Comment: Que debería finalizar con `\0`... ¿Has probado tu solución?

Comment: Pues la probé y funcionó, pero tiene sentido lo que dices.

Comment: Salvo que tengas la suerte de que en esa posición de memoria se encontrase un carácter nulo la función iba a fallar. Si te funcionó yo probaría a echar la lotería (probabilidad de 1 entre 256)

Answer (score 0):

yo hubiera asignado menos memoría desde la cadena 1 a la 2 jaja

```
malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+2)
```

Este podría ser un strcpy propio:

```
char *mi_strcpy(char *cadena1, char *cadena2) {
    char *cadena = malloc(strlen(cadena1)+strlen(cadena2)+2);
    sprintf(cadena, "%c", 0);
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(cadena1); i++) {
        sprintf(cadena, "%s%c", cadena, cadena1[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(cadena2); i++) {
        sprintf(cadena, "%s%c", cadena, cadena2[i]);
    }
    return cadena;
}
```

Uso:

```
int main() {
    char *mi_copia = mi_strcpy("hola ", "mundo");
    printf("%s\n", mi_copia);
    free(mi_copia);
}
```