# Punteros como parámetros a funciones en C

Tags: c, punteros

Hola gente tengo un pequeno problema. Estoy creando una funcion que reciba como parámetro un puntero doble. Esa funciôn recibe el parámetro y le asigna memoria dinámica. Una vez asignada la memoria, llamo a otra función que le asigna valores a ese puntero. Pero al hacer la asignación de valores me da error de segmentación, sospecho que el problema esta en el paso de punteros como parámetro, pues cuando hago todo en el `main` y no en funciones, no presenta problema. Les paso los códigos, así alguien puede orientarme.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define dim 100 


void asignarMemoriaDinamica(double** A){
        int i;

        A=malloc(dim*sizeof(double*));      

        for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
            A[i]=malloc(dim*sizeof(double));    
        }
    }
void cargarA(double** A){
    int i,j;
    srand(time(NULL));  

    for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++){
            int test = rand()%200 -100;
            A[i][j]=test;   //al ejecutar esta linea da error
            printf("%.2lf ",A[i][j]);   
        }
        printf("%s","\n");
    }
}
int main() {

    double **A;
    asignarMemoriaDinamica(A);
    cargarA(A);     

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como ya comenté en [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51207/strcpy-en-c-con-punteros)...

```
void asignarMemoriaDinamica(double** A){
  A=malloc(dim*sizeof(double*));   
}
```

Los cambios en `A` son única y exclusivamente locales. Para que los cambios se reflejen fuera de la función tienes que trabajar con un nivel de indirección adicional (en este caso un puntero triple):

```
void asignarMemoriaDinamica(double*** A){
  *A=malloc(dim*sizeof(double*));   
}
```

En la función `cargarA` no vas a tener ese problema porque no estás cambiando la dirección apuntada por `A` sino que trabajas directamente sobre la memoria direccionada por `A` (que no es lo mismo).

¿Cómo se llama a esta nueva función?

```
double **A = 0; // No hay que perder las buenas costumbres
asignarMemoriaDinamica(&A);
```

Comment: Por lo que entiendo los cambios a A seran locales a menos que le pase la direccion de memoria de mi puntero A declarado en el main, lo que no tengo claro es como debo llamar a mi funcion desde el main . Tengo entendido que para pasar direcciones de memoria (y que los cambios se mantengan en mis variables parametros) debo usar el & en la llamada. Como dije por las pruebas que hice esto no funciona. Mi variable declarada debe ser ahora puntero triple ***?  No consigo dar con la llamada a la funcion que me dijiste de manera correcta. Si puedes mostrarme un ejemplo te lo agradezco.

Comment: @Patricio he editado la respuesta para añadir un ejemplo de uso.

Comment: void asignarMemoriaDinamica(double*** A){
  int i;
  
  *A=malloc(10*sizeof(double*));  
  if(A==NULL){
   printf("ERROR");
  }  
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   *A[i]=(double*)malloc(10*sizeof(double)); 
  }
 }                                                                                                         int main() {
 double**   A=0 ; 

 asignarMemoriaDinamica(&A);
  
 
 return 0;
}    Has probado tu codigo, este es mi codigo y no funciona.

Comment: @Patricio Mi código funciona... Deberías fijarte en el uso de los asteriscos...

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {

    double **A;
    asignarMemoriaDinamica(&A);
    cargarA(&A);     

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Eso fue lo primero que probe, pero me da error de incompatibilidad en el pasaje de argumentos.

Comment: Deberías asegurarte (en la medida de lo posible) de que el código que publicas compila. Tu solución es errónea porque `&A` es una referencia a un puntero doble o, dicho de otra forma, `&A` es un puntero triple y ninguna de las dos funciones admite ese tipo de variable. Por otro lado considera proporcionar una descripción de tu respueta para que la misma quede más clara y entendible... piensa que no todo el mundo posee el mismo nivel de conocimientos.